# SVG files and UIWebView missing data

Tags: ios, svg, uiwebview

what I'm trying to do is to open some SVGs in my app with AFNetworking class, the file is opened but I miss some data.

When I try to open it with Safari I can see it right.

The xml code I miss is:

```
<g stroke-width="0.25" clip-path="url(#clipId0)" fill="rgb(0,0,255)"      stroke="none" >
<text transform="matrix(7.16352e-017 -1.16989 1.16989 7.16352e-017 701.776 462.386)" font-family=",'sans-serif'" font-size="1.299"      style="font-family: txt" >2009123351</text>
</g>
```

What I should see is 2009123351 but I just can's see, the other code is ok.

Any idea why I miss that?

Thanx so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the svg and the zoom factor, once we zoomed out the original file and then converted to the svg we successfully found the missing data.